# Yelp Integration in Android

Tags: android, yelp

I have to integrate yelp api in my android app. I have never done it so need a bit of help.
I want to know how do I start, what all things are required, etc.

I tried implementing this code  https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/java/Yelp.java in android.
It gives a NoSuchMethodError at line request.send()

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Yelp Integration in Android:

**Step 1:** Register to Yelp site. You will require Yelp keys. [Register here](http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started) . Get API access.

**Step 2:** You need to have scribe-1.2.1.jar in your project. [Get it here](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/downloads).

**Step 3:** Add these 2 files in your project: [Yelp.java](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/java/Yelp.java) and [YelpApi2.java](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/java/YelpApi2.java).

**Step 4:** You can remove the main() method from the Yelp.java and instead call the Yelp.search() from your activity. Search() takes 3 arguements: term,latitude and longitude.
Term is the thing you want to search(eg. restaurants,bars,etc.).

**Step 5:** When you send the request, you get a json response. Parse the response to get the data. For more information on json response parameters, [See this](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api).

Follow these steps and you will be able to do Yelp Integration in your Android.
See the the Api documentation provided by Yelp.

Another example which I found out: [Yelp Example](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Web/eatright/com/eatrightapp/external/yelp/v2/YelpService.java.htm)

Comment: I've read that it's free, and in some place they say they pay you. How does this work? For what operations do they pay you?

Answer (score 0):

First Register to Yelp site than go to [click here](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/authentication)

than click on Make API Access and create your own outhentication key . Replace these key to github demo than run it ..its work .