# Need to Find Nearby Restaurants Android

Tags: android, location, google-places-api, yelp

I'm making an app for school that will show your location and display nearby pizza restaurants. I've looked into both the Yelp api and the Google Places api, but I'm not sure of the pros and cons of each.

It seems that Yelp would work a little better because it will have reviews. While this is true, I haven't seen any good resources about learning Yelp with android.

Comment: maybe this can help you with Yelp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676733/yelp-integration-in-android