# Yelp API Android Integration

Tags: java, android, api, yelp

I am attempting to integrate with the Yelp API for Android.

I keep getting fatal errors whenever I am trying to connect.

```
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cse.usf.edu.android/cse.usf.edu.android.HelloWorldActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1178)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:245)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at org.scribe.model.Response.<init>(Response.java:27)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at org.scribe.model.Request.doSend(Request.java:110)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:62)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:12)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at cse.usf.edu.android.Yelp.search(Yelp.java:58)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at cse.usf.edu.android.HelloWorldActivity.onCreate(HelloWorldActivity.java:22)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
10-14 18:32:29.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7354):     ... 11 more
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cse.usf.edu.android/cse.usf.edu.android.HelloWorldActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1178)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:245)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at org.scribe.model.Response.<init>(Response.java:27)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at org.scribe.model.Request.doSend(Request.java:110)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:62)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:12)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at cse.usf.edu.android.Yelp.search(Yelp.java:58)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at cse.usf.edu.android.HelloWorldActivity.onCreate(HelloWorldActivity.java:22)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
10-14 18:32:36.965: E/AndroidRuntime(7439):     ... 11 more
```

I have done the following:

**1.** Registered for Yelp API

**2.** Downloaded [scribe 1.3.0](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/downloads), and added it to the `libs` folder

**3.** Added two classes [Yelp.java](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/java/Yelp.java) and [YelpApi2.java](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/java/YelpApi2.java) to the `src` folder

**4.** Removed the `main` function from Yelp API and I have added the Yelp call to my main activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world);

    // Update tokens here from Yelp developers site, Manage API access.
    String consumerKey = "secret";
    String consumerSecret = "secret";
    String token = "secret";
    String tokenSecret = "secret";

    Yelp yelp = new Yelp(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, tokenSecret);
    String response = yelp.search("burritos", 30.361471, -87.164326);

}
```

(Of course, were `secret` is my actual information from Yelp)

I am rather new to Android, so I have a feeling it is something simple, but I can't quite figure out the issue, as I have followed Yelp's examples and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676733/yelp-integration-in-android) exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the exception is pretty clear: You're trying to access the network from the main (UI) thread. The UI thread should be reserved for handling UI events to ensure that your app doesn't stop responding, and you should perform other tasks (like networking or calculations) on a background thread.

Comment: Ok, I was unsure what that exception meant. So I will have to create a thread which calls the Yelp API? I suppose I can run this thread from my main activity?

Comment: @BarryTormey The question I linked to has sample code for how to run a task in a background thread. You *can* (and should) create the async task in your main thread, then dispatch it to run in the background.